# Find a basis for the set of all $n \times n$ skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand what the basis must look like by considering lower dimensions, but I don't know how to represent the basis in a set.

Comment: *"I understand what the basis must look like by considering lower dimensions"*: what do you mean by that? Can you come up with a basis, for example, of the $2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3$ skew-symmetric matrices?

Comment: What is a lower dimension?

Comment: ya that's what i meant

Comment: Do you know what a basis is?

Comment: yup, it's a set that needs to span the subspace and it needs to be linearly independent

Comment: Do you see any relationship between the set of skew matrices and the set of strictly upper triangular matrices? Can you find a basis for the latter, and if so, how to modify it so that it forms a basis for the former?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For a given $n$, let $E_{ij}$ denote the $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are all zero except for the $i,j$ entry, which is a $1$.  Consider the matrices $E_{ij} - E_{ji}$.  How can we use these to form a basis?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Skew-symmetric matrices are specified by the part above the diagonal (why?).
- What is a basis for these upper-triangular matrices?
- How do I decompose a matrix into symmetric and skew-symmetric parts?