# Prove that V1 and V2 are subspaces and find a basis for them

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem:
for $n>1$ 
 $$V=M_n(\mathbb{K})$$ 
$$V_1 = \{ A\in V\mid A = A^{\top} \}$$
$$V_2 = \{A\in V\mid A= -A^{\top}\}$$

I need to show that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces for $V$ and to find a basis for them.

Comment: And [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458246/find-a-basis-for-set-of-all-n-by-n-skew-symmetric-matrices) is the basis for $V_2$.

Comment: A basis for $V_1$ is given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620757/find-a-basis-for-the-vector-space-of-symmetric-matrices-with-an-order-of-n-tim), which is itself a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

As noted by @ncmathsadist you can easily see that the transpose operation is linear, so $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces.

To find  the basis you can start from the case $n=2$ and you easily see that a matrix in $V_1$ can be expressed as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
b&a
\end{bmatrix}=
a\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
+b\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
+c\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
and, since the matrices at the right are linearly independent, these are a basis.

Can you generalize to $n>2$? and do the same for $V_2$? Starting from the fact that, for $n=2$ a matrix in $V_2$ has the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&b\\
-b&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$